# How to know when scanf has aborted?

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

If user enters `'E'`, then what will be stored in `n`?
I have to stop taking input when user enters `'E'` and I take input as an integer.

Comment: You are scanning "E" with %d format specifier?

Comment: actually i have to take integers as input and stop taking input when user enter E

Comment: Why in the world would you use E? Just use a value which your program will not use - maybe like -1?

Comment: the end of input is signified by N having a value of E. here N is integer type

Comment: if the user can enter `E`, *don't* read the input to an integer.

Comment: its not in my hand, i got this Question in a competition

Comment: `he end of input is signified by N having a value of E.` -- then make `n` char?! No?

Comment: @Karoly then what else could be the type?? I have to use N as integer if it is not E

Comment: string, *then* convert.

Comment: scanf("%s",&n);
if(n=="E")
break;
else
atoi(n);

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Why not `scanf("%c", &n)`?

Comment: Should it also abort if user enters any other letter? What should happen in that case that is different of entering an 'E'?

Comment: while(scanf("%d", %n) == 1) {
    // do something with n
}

Answer (score 2):

[`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns number of matched elements.

> **Return Value**
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

You can do something like:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    // do something with n
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check what scanf returns. If you type "E" and have %d then you will have so called *matching failure*.
Check the following scanf manual page (it's for linux but should be the same in general): [scanf man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score -2):

You need to get information from `scanf` on two things:

1. Whether it assigned anything to `n`, and
2. How many characters has it consumed (if you're using `sscanf`).

`scanf` returns how many assignments it has done. So if it succeeded at all in assigning to `n`, it will return 1, otherwise it'll return 0.

I'm assuming here that the input is supposed to be a floating point written out as `mantissaEexponent`, but this is just for the purposes of illustration. For standard input (`scanf`):

```
int mantissa, exponent;
int mantissaSet = 0, int exponentSet = 0;
mantissaSet = scanf("%d", &mantissa); 
char c = getc();
if (c != EOF && c == 'E') {
  exponentSet = scanf("%d", &exponent);
}
if (mantissaSet) { ... /* mantissa was set */ }
if (exponentSet) { ... /* exponent was set */ }
```

When getting input from a string, you need to know where to look for `'E'` if there is one in the input, so you need to add a `%n` conversion to get this information out. The code below illustrates how it would work for strings (with `sscanf`):

```
const char * string = "1234E56";
int mantissa, exponent;
int mantissaSet = 0, exponentSet = 0;
int charCount = 0;
int mantissaSet = sscanf(string, "%d%n", &mantissa, &charCount);
if (string + charCount == 'E') {
   exponentSet = sscanf(string + charCount + 1, "%d%n", &exponent, &charCount);
   ...
}
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: How is it unrelevant is beyond me. The asker clearly wants to get a seemingly optional integer, then an optional E followed by an integer. I've shown how to do just that, using both `scanf` and `sscanf`, because the technique with `sscanf` is different. This is for completeness. I don't think that one-liners are really useful with newb-style questions where clearly more guidance is needed. There's this thing called pedagogy, you know. Those newb answers are not in a vacuum.

Comment: "I have to stop taking input when user enters 'E'" - I guess E stands for Exit.